# controlling retropie + kodi with the skywriter hat

Tags: retropie

Hi I'm a bit of a noob just wanting to know if controlling retropie with the skywriter hat is possible? I would like to turn on my pi, scroll through emulators/roms and start roms with the skywriter. Then use my ps controller for playing games.
Also would I be able to do the same with kodi. Scroll through video/music and launch songs and movies with the skywriter?

Could i use the script from github 
https://github.com/pimoroni/skywriter-hat/blob/master/library/README.md

or would i need to find a new script.
Any info will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: How are you going to be running the code to read the gestures if the pi is off?

Comment: should be possible. start with emulating a keyboard, https://github.com/pimoroni/skywriter-hat/blob/master/examples/keyboard.py